# Ef creates foreign key property in shadow state

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have database structure with one to many relationship, and need to declare string field as primary key. But EF creates the foreign key property 'Property name' in shadow state. As a result I get other `Property name1` column.

Database entities:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new();

    public string IncidentName { get; set; }

    public Incident Incident { get; set; }
}

public class Incident
{    
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string IncidentName { get; set; }

    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

Message:

> The foreign key property 'Account.IncidentName1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'IncidentName' exists in the entity type, but is either
> not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type.

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one to one relationship between `Account` and `Incident`, `IncidentName` repeating twice.  Cannot same property name in One to one. So you have to change name of the one of both.

```
public class Incident
{    
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string IncidentId { get; set; }

    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```